# Global variable in laravel not working after upgrading 7 to 8

Tags: php, laravel

I upgraded the laravel from 7 to 8 and it works very well except for the global variables.
this is my sample:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $contact = App\Contact::all();
    $topbar = App\Topbar::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get();

    $view->with('contact',$contact)
    ->with('topbar',$topbar);

});
```

you can find this code in official docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views

Comment: There's no change in the View composer functionality in Laravel 8 so it should work if it worked in Laravel 7. Models are placed in `App\Models` directory in Laravel 8 so cross check if you have moved your models when upgrading. To check for namespace errors you can `dd($contact, $topbar)` in the above snippet. And lastly check whether you have written the above snippet in the `boot()` method of a service provider and if you created a new service provider then it is included in the providers array in `config\app.php`

Comment: In your above snippet namespace should be absolute like `$contact = \App\Contact::all()` and `$topbar = \App\Topbar::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get()` - preceded by `\`

Comment: `App\Models\Contact::all();` and `App\Models\Topbar::orderBy('sortorder', 'asc')->get();`

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: i get this error:
Undefined variable: topbar